# Empty WebView Grow heap?

Tags: java, android, webview

First, I am new in android and searched a lot bout Grow heap and in all docs, they say Grow heap means memory leak in activity,
I have an empty activity with an empty WebView , 
why this activity always got "Grow heap" log on logcat

But when I removed WebView from layout >>>>, tada > there is no Grow heap !!

**is WebView is a really bad thing ?**

activity :

```
package com.my.app;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class admin_new extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_new);
        Log.i("iam","started");
    }

}
```

layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat :

```
11-15 05:53:57.143 27259-27259/com.my.app I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 11.523MB for 1127536-byte allocation
```

**Note** :

- I use connected Samsung GTI9300 (API 18) to Run my app
- This activity is default activity

**EDIT :**
I'v put logcat filter on "No filter" and tested all apps in my phone !
Instagram , Facebook , Shazam , contacts , Clock , even calculator !!!
all they have Grow heap between **10MB** to **20MB** !!!
whats that really mean ?